# vba filter update in function

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason the filter doesn't apply as I cannot see any changes. The function seems to enter the correct values, but only if I manually click OK in the "custom filter" it updates the screen.

So I guess I'm missing an update filter option or something.

Code:

```
Function filter(weekstart As Date, weekend As Date)

    With Worksheets("Rawdata")
    .Range("A:N").AutoFilter _
        field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & weekstart & "", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & weekend & "", _
        VisibleDropDown:=True

    End With

End Function
```

Thx for the help

/////////////// EDIT
To clarify. It shows the correct date/time values and if I click manually OK it then updates the filter and shows the correct values. Very strange
[image]

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdate = false` perhaps?

Comment: how / where do you call this function ?

Comment: I call it from within a SUB with   makefilter = filter(weekstart, weekend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps use

```
Function filter(weekstart As Date, weekend As Date)

    With Worksheets("Rawdata")
    .Range("A:N").AutoFilter _
        field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(weekstart) & "", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(weekend) & "", _
        VisibleDropDown:=True

    End With

End Function
```

VBA defaults to US date formats whenever possible so it's safer to use the numeric values

Answer (score 0):

And what about this?

```
Worksheets("Rawdata").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
```

Comment: The only option I see then is the aforementioned ScreenUpdate. Bear in mind that this is not a normal behaviour (this information should be updated automatically).

Comment: very strange. I really don't know whats going on. I updated the original post

Comment: The VBA code seems OK and should update everything automatically (otherwise, the proposed "forcing updates" should do the job). By dismissing the option that something might be wrong in your Excel program (or some kind of incompatility might be present), the only reason I see is that this code is not properly called (not explaining why the values are being copied,  though). Just to make completely sure, you should replace the "Function" with "Sub" (because this is not a Function) and call it directly, not from another function; from the click event of a Button, for example.

Comment: do I put the Worksheets("Rawdata").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter before the End With or after?

Comment: Put it after the filter has been created (in or out the with is the same). Copy all this code into the sub associated with the click event of a button to make completely sure that the problem is not somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your criteria ..

```
Criteria1:=">= #" & format(weekstart,"dd.mm.yyyy") & "#", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<= #" & format(weekend,"dd.mm.yyyy") & "#"
```

And it should be **Sub Filter** since it doesn't give return value ..

Comment: just puts the hastags in front and end of the date... doesn't work

Comment: still doesn't do anything. The strange thing is it copies the date into the fields (see the screenshot) but doesn't execute them. When I click on OK it then applies the filter.... thats what I'm missing in VBA